# Quickblox User registration "Error reasons:(null)" IOS

Tags: ios, registration, quickblox

While registering user to quickblox its giving the error "Error reasons:(null)"

Edit :- More to add also getting same error when creating dialog.

So it is difficult to debug what exactly is the issue.
Is there something which i could be missing at my end?

Comment: Kiran, please ensure that you use QuickBlox iOS SDK 2.6.5+. We improved errors logging and you will see correct error reasons.

Comment: Hi @SevenDays i have integraed 2.6.6.

Still randomly i am getting same issue "Error reasons:(null)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't set credential properly for registration of user. 
Check all the parameters you have set correctly or not.
If you are not able to understand kindly check example on below link,

[Getting started](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Oh.2C_please.2C_please_show_me_the_code)

You need to set your parameter in below method to create user.

> ```
> QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
> user.login = @"garry";
> user.password = @"garry5santos";
>
> [QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
>     // Success, do something
> } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
>     // error handling
>     NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);
> }];
> ```

and if you are using real time chat loging thnen set parameter in this method,

> use real time features you have to be logged in to Chat:
>
> ```
> QBUUser *currentUser = [QBUUser user];
> currentUser.ID = 2569; // your current user's ID
> currentUser.password = @"garrySant88"; // your current user's password   
>
> [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:user completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
>     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
> }];
> ```

Note :- In quickblox documentation they provide all the information in detail and with example . so, please first try to understand examples provided by quickblox and it will be bit easy to understand for you.

**Don't confuse with this,**

User.login can not be email address but it will be your login username.

user.password is the email address or username password.

Comment: Hi Badal, I am using the same code as you have mentioned above.

But this issue is coming randomly and not every time. So its very difficult to debug it.

Comment: have you created user successfully or facing issue while registration ? i think you need to check credential proper. and which server you are using ?

Comment: Am randomly facing this issue.

User is getting registered sometimes and sometimes the error "Error reason: (null)" is coming. And i am confused about your question that which server i am using. Its Quickblox server?

Comment: How did you know that user got registered sometimes?

Comment: Because am getting success response in completion block. And also i can check in admin panel in Quickblox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105228/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-kiran).

Comment: Hi badal sorry i was not able to respond yesterday. If you will have time. I will wait for you in our chat room.